# Intercept of linear projection

Tags: regression, linear-model, projection

I'm reading a paper and wondering whether I get things right: Say I have a variable Y and two further variables $X_1$ and $X_2$. I want to determine the part of $Y$ which is not linearly explained by $X_1$ and $X_2$ (that's what the paper says). To do so I would do a linear projection of $Y$ on $X_1$ and $X_2$. The intercept in this linear projection should then be the part of $Y$ which is not linearly explained by $X_1$ and $X_2$, is it? The framework in the paper is a bit more complicated and I'm just wondering whether I get this key point right.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is nothing in this setup that ordinarily is termed an "intercept."  If you *assume* Y is a linear combination of the $X_i$ and a constant, then your characterization would make sense (and be correct).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant! Thank you for confirming and making me aware of the correct framing for my question.